Approach to apply liner gradient style on area charts using google charts
I am trying to solve an area chart development but I see the exact style as difficult to achieve.
I am using google charts to develop this but I am struggling with

How to apply linear gradient in both data area which turns white towards 0 line.
How to center my liner gradient spread to the peak data points (In below pic, its on June)


Attaching 2nd pic of my situation with google charts

My google chart code.
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Month', 'KWH', 'KWH'],
        ['JAN', -250, 800],
        ['APRIL', -240, 810],
        ['JUN', -250, 900],
        ['SEP', -240, 800],
        ['DEC', -200, 700]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: '',
        colors: ['#00B55F', '#FFC52D'],
        chartArea: {               
            width: '88%',  // Adjust width
            height: '80%'  // Adjust height
        },
        hAxis: { title: 'Month', titleTextStyle: { color: '#FFC52D0' }, backgroundColor: 'FFC52D0' },
        vAxis: { minValue: -400, ticks: [-400, -200, 0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000] }

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('area_chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}


This is something I think very near to what you are looking for and its not very ideal solution as it basically does repaint of linearGradient of svg on top of generated graph. Few pointers I got from here on how to approach for this. Check comments on the code and tweak few things to modify behavior of linearGradient.
End result looks like below.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
      google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var baseColors = ['#00B55F', '#FFC52D'];
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Month', 'KWH', 'KWH'],
                ['JAN', -250, 800],
                ['APRIL', -240, 810],
                ['JUN', -250, 900],
                ['SEP', -240, 800],
                ['DEC', -200, 700]
            ]);

        var options = {
        title: '',
        colors: baseColors,
        legend: 'none',
        chartArea: {               
            width: '88%', 
            height: '80%' 
        },
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        areaOpacity: 1,
        hAxis: { title: 'Month', titleTextStyle: { color: '#FFC52D0' }, backgroundColor: 'FFC52D0' },
        vAxis: { minValue: -400, ticks: [-400, -200, 0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000] }
    };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        // Draw the chart and then apply the gradient
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
          applyGradients(data,options);
        });

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      function applyGradients(data,options) {
      
        var svg = document.querySelector('#chart_div svg');

        if (svg) {
          var defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
          svg.appendChild(defs);

          // get all path elements
          var paths = svg.querySelectorAll('path');
          //ugly hack to ignore legend paths
          if(options.legend != 'none'){
            paths = Array.from(paths);
            paths = paths.slice(options.colors.length,paths.length);
            console.log(paths);
          }
          // Iterate over each path and apply the corresponding gradient
          paths.forEach(function(path, index) {
            if (index < options.colors.length) {
              var baseColor = options.colors[index];
              var gradientId = 'gradient-' + index;

              var linearGradient = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'linearGradient');
              linearGradient.setAttribute('id', gradientId);
              
              // Determine the gradient direction based on the data values as we have positive and negative values
              var isNegative = false;
              for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
                if (data.getValue(i, index + 1) < 0) {
                  isNegative = true;
                  break;
                }
              }

              if (isNegative) {
                // Negative values: Gradient from top to bottom
                linearGradient.setAttribute('x1', '0%');
                linearGradient.setAttribute('y1', '0%');
                linearGradient.setAttribute('x2', '0%');
                linearGradient.setAttribute('y2', '100%');
              } else {
                // Positive values: Gradient from bottom to top
                linearGradient.setAttribute('x1', '0%');
                linearGradient.setAttribute('y1', '100%');
                linearGradient.setAttribute('x2', '0%');
                linearGradient.setAttribute('y2', '0%');
              }

              // Define the stops for the gradient
              var stop1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'stop');
              stop1.setAttribute('offset', '90%');
              stop1.setAttribute('style', `stop-color:${baseColor};stop-opacity:0`);//change 0 to 0.1 or 0.2 if you dont want start color as white
              linearGradient.appendChild(stop1);

              var stop2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'stop');
              stop2.setAttribute('offset', '100%');
              stop2.setAttribute('style', `stop-color:${baseColor};stop-opacity:1`);//change 1 to 0.9 or 0.8 if you dont want end color as same as base color
              linearGradient.appendChild(stop2);

              defs.appendChild(linearGradient);

              // Apply the gradient to the path
              path.setAttribute('fill', `url(#${gradientId})`);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>

